# Android : Display Unicode text in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, user-interface

I am loading Spanish text words from SQlite db and displaying the words in android.
I am having an issue with words containing special chars like "toméselo" - the letter "é" is making an issue:

[These are the records in the sqlite db:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8h0N.png)

[These are the words as seen by the AutoCompleteTextView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfodv.png)

This is my AutoCompleteTextView ui definition:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView" />
```

And this is my java method filling in the AutoCompleteTextView:

```
        wordForTranslation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //here is your code
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The key has been pressed!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wordForTranslation.setAdapter(null);

            String nativeWord=wordForTranslation.getText().toString();

            try {
                Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select native_word from dictionary where native_word like'" + nativeWord + "%' order by Length(native_word) asc limit 10;", null);

                resultSet.moveToFirst();
                ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(!resultSet.isAfterLast()) {
                    words.add(resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("native_word")));
                    resultSet.moveToNext();
                }
                resultSet.close();

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, words.toArray(new String[0]));

                wordForTranslation.setAdapter(adapter);


                resultSet.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The word: "+wordForTranslation.getText()+" does not exist in the dictionary !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            //autocomplete key listener

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I searched for the solution for the issue but had no success.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the encoding of your SQLite db? You can check it with `PRAGMA encoding; `

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina That setting has no effect on the encoding used in the API.

Comment: Executing PRAGMA encoding;  Gives me "UTF-8", so this will not resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you solve the issue? If so then would you please share the solution?